# Deleting specific rows - SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, common-table-expression, sql-delete, dbeaver

I'm trying to delete duplicate rows from my table 'exchange_transactions' associated with the surgeon name 'Lucille Torres' using a cte. The transaction_id column should be unique but is duplicated in this case hence the attempt to delete them. I tried this code but it doesn't seem to work. Replacing 'DELETE' with 'SELECT *' shows me all the rows I want to delete. What am I doing wrong?

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        transaction_id,
        surgeon,  
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY 
                transaction_id
        ) row_num
        FROM exchange_transactions)
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE surgeon = 'Lucille Torres' AND row_num > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Deleting directly from a CTE won't work in SqLite.

But if that table has a primary key (f.e. `id`)
then the result of the CTE can be used in the delete.

**For example:**

```
WITH CTE_DUPS AS
(
  SELECT id,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY surgeon, transaction_id
      ORDER BY id) AS rn
  FROM exchange_transactions
  WHERE surgeon = 'Lucille Torres'
)
DELETE 
FROM exchange_transactions
WHERE id IN (select id from CTE_DUPS where rn > 1)
```

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=e7953b4fca89206b42051406ceb454d5)*

Answer (score 0):

Use the column [`ROWID`](https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html) to get the minimum value for each `transaction_id` that you will not delete:

```
delete from exchange_transactions
where surgeon = 'Lucille Torres'
and exists (
  select 1 from exchange_transactions t
  where t.surgeon = exchange_transactions.surgeon
    and t.transaction_id = exchange_transactions.transaction_id 
    and t.rowid < exchange_transactions.rowid
)
```